# Printing the wrong text and getting results randomly

Tags: processing

Here's my code, where lastLine checks the last of the file:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;

    public String lastLine( File file ) {
    RandomAccessFile fileHandler = null;
    try {
        fileHandler = new RandomAccessFile( file, "r" );
        long fileLength = fileHandler.length() - 1;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for(long filePointer = fileLength; filePointer != -1; filePointer--){
            fileHandler.seek( filePointer );
            int readByte = fileHandler.readByte();

            if( readByte == 0xA ) {
                if( filePointer == fileLength ) {
                    continue;
                }
                break;

            } else if( readByte == 0xD ) {
                if( filePointer == fileLength - 1 ) {
                    continue;
                }
                break;
            }

            sb.append( ( char ) readByte );
        }

        String lastLine = sb.reverse().toString();
        return lastLine;
    } catch( java.io.FileNotFoundException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch( java.io.IOException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } finally {
        if (fileHandler != null )
            try {
                fileHandler.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                /* ignore */
            }
    }
}
    File file = new File("lines.txt");
    String last = lastLine(file);
    String previous = null;

float r = random(0,255);
float g = random(0, 255);
float b = random(0, 255);



    public void settings() {
        size(500, 500);
    }
    public void setup() {
      frameRate(60);
        stroke(155, 0, 0);
        textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
        textSize(30);
                background(r+(random(0,100)), g+(random(0,100)), b+(random(0,100)));
    }

    void draw() {

      previous = lastLine(file);

      if (last.equals(previous)) {
        last = lastLine(file);
      }

      if (!last.equals(previous)) {
          if (last.indexOf("w") != -1) {
            text("there is a w", 255, 255);
            fill(r, g, b);
          }
          else {
            text("there is not a w", 255, 255);
          }
        fill(50);
        last = lastLine(file);
      }
    }
```

So whenever the last line of the file has been changed, the text printed on screen should change to "there is a w" or "there is not a w" depending on whether or not there is a w in the last line. However, I seem to be getting results randomly. For example, when the last string of the file contains a "w," sometimes I get "there is not a w" printed on the screen. I've also gotten "there is a w" for when there is no w in the string.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Where is `lastLine` function? And file? We can't run this code... Hard to say

Comment: @v.k. Sorry, I've edited it to include the entire file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is doing some strange things: why are you reading in the file 3 separate times in the `draw()` function? Why are you reading in the file one byte at a time?

Instead of trying to go through your code, here is an example that seems to do what you want:

```
String previous;

void draw() {
  String current = lastLine();
  if (!current.equals(previous)) {
    background(random(255), random(255), random(255));

    if (current.contains("w")) {
      text("YES W", 0, 50);
    } else {
      text("NO W", 0, 50);
    }
  }

  previous = current;
}

public String lastLine() {
  String lines[] = loadStrings("list.txt");

  if(lines.length == 0){
    return "";
  }

  return lines[lines.length-1];
}
```

Also note that if you're not going to be deploying as JavaScript, you might want to use Java's [file watch service](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) instead of reading in the file every frame.

Comment: This is a lot cleaner. Still relatively new to coding. Thanks!